# How to rotate a CAD drawing in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I'm trying to rotate the artboard to the desired angle on the Forge Viewer, it looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to do this on Forge Viewer?
I am using Forge Viewer SDK latest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article explaining how to rotate sheets in the Forge Viewer : [Rotate sheets in the viewer](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/rotate-sheets-viewer).